# Hibernate: Reuse hibernate class

Tags: hibernate, inheritance

I have 2 table in the database with the exact columns.

May I know is it possible to have a abstract class and extend it for the 2 table.

example abstract table

table a extends table.
table b extends table.

I have read inheritance but it doesn't seems to fit my needs
http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.4/apache-openjpa-1.0.4/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_inher.html#jpa_overview_mapping_inher_single

I don't see how I could specify the table name.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

```
public abstract class Table {

    private String commonField;

    @Column(name = "COMMON_FIELD")
    public String getCommonField() {
        return commonField;
    }

    public void setCommonField(String commonField) {
        this.commonField = commonField;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
public class TableA extends Table {

    // table_a fields only

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
public class TableB extends Table {

    // table_b fields only

}
```

Comment: what if: the column name are different?

Comment: You said *2 table in the database with the exact [same] columns*. If the names are different, you can't factorize them, cause the two columns aren't identical actually.

Comment: I just tested this today. Is only partially working for some reason, hibernate won't look at the abstract class to get fields BUT only the main class. so when you update. abstract class won't be initialize for some reaosn.

Comment: Have you tried to put an `@Entity` over the abstract class too?

Comment: i tried that but it doesn't work too...i will go home try again.. is there anyway way to use hibernate strategy to achieve this too?